# Escaping quotes in zsh alias

Tags: shell, zsh, quoting, alias

Following on from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6910/12) about stripping newlines out of text, I want to turn this into a zsh alias as follows:

```
alias striplines=' awk " /^$/ {print \"\n\"; } /./ {printf( \" %s \",$0);}"'
```

I've tried escaping the quotes inside the awk script, but I'm getting this error:

```
awk: (FILENAME=bspsrobustness FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

(The file is called `bspsrobustness`)

Is there a way to do what I want? I suppose I could turn this into an awk script rather than a zsh alias, is that my best option?

Comment: By the way, this applies to all (Bourne-style, not csh) shells.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use a zsh function instead of an alias. No quoting hoops to jump through.

```
striplines() {
    awk '... awk body "with quotes" ...' "$@"
}
```

Comment: And then how would I call it: `striplines filename`?

Comment: could you explain what the `"$@"` is doing?

Comment: @Seamus, yes you'd call it exactly like that. The `"$@"` syntax sends the striplines arguments to awk undisturbed -- necessary if, say, any of your filenames contain spaces: `striplines "file 1" "file 2"` would sent two filenames to awk.

Answer (score 7):

To get an idea of what's going on, run

```
% alias striplines='print -lr awk " /^$/ {print \"\n\"; } /./ {printf( \" %s \",$0);}"'
% striplines
awk
 /^$/ {print "\n"; } /./ {printf( " %s ",zsh);}
```

Since the `$` characters are in double quotes (when they're expanded after the alias is expanded), they are interpreted by the shell. To get the quoting right, it's easier to put the whole alias definition in single quotes. What's inside the single quotes is what will be expanded when the alias is used. Now that the argument of `awk` is surrounded in double quotes, it's clear that you need backslashes before `\"$`.

```
alias striplines='print -lr awk " /^\$/ {print \"\n\"; } /./ {printf( \" %s \",\$0);}"'
```

A useful idiom to single-quote a single-quoted string is that `'\''` is pretty much a way to put a literal single quote in a single-quoted string. Technically there's a juxtaposition of a single-quoted string, a backslash-quoted `'`, and another single-quoted string. The juxtaposed empty string `''` at the end can be removed.

```
alias striplines='print -lr awk '\'' /^$/ {print "\n"; } /./ {printf( " %s ",$0);}'\'
```

After this long explanation, a recommendation: when it's too complicated  for an alias, [use a function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7951/escaping-quotes-in-zsh-alias/7966#7966).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `zsh`, you might also turn on the [`rcquotes`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-RCQUOTES) option:

> Allow the character sequence `''` to signify a single quote within singly quoted strings. Note this does not apply in quoted strings using the format `$'...'`, where a backslashed single quote can be used.

Thus, instead of

```
alias striplines='print -lr awk '\'' /^$/ {print "\n"; } /./ {printf( " %s ",$0);}'\'
```

using `rcquotes` you could write

```
setopt rcquotes
alias striplines='print -lr awk '' /^$/ {print "\n"; } /./ {printf( " %s ",$0);}'''
```

or, by using `$'...'` you could write

```
alias striplines=$'print -lr awk \' /^$/ {print "\n"; } /./ {printf( " %s ",$0);}\''
```