# Scaping single quota in zsh alias

Tags: zsh, alias, escape-characters

I like create any alias for docker commandas, and I need any alias use single quotes.

I see post [Escaping quotes in zsh alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7951/escaping-quotes-in-zsh-alias) but not work for me.

Tried in .zshrc

```
function dinfoip() {
   docker inspect --format "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" "$1"
}
```

Also

```
function dinfoip() {
   docker inspect --format '"{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}"' "$1"
}
```

Get same error

```
dinfo 2870                                                                                                       
zsh: parse error near `.NetworkSettings.Net...'
zsh: parse error in command substitution
```

Original commad

```
docker inspect --format "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" 2870                          
> 172.17.0.2
```

After correct mistake using `-format` instead `--format` in function

```
function dinfoip() {
   docker inspect --format "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" "$1"
}
```

Get other error

```
...
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
Error: No such object: –format
Error: No such object: {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}
```

Comment: After fixing your functions  to use `--format` instead of `-format`, they work fine enough for me.

Comment: I fixed mistake and use --format but error is other:

```Error: No such object: –format
Error: No such object: {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}```

Comment: Are your writing this in Word or something like that? `-` is the en dash. It should be `--` - two hyphens/dashes.

Comment: I dont' use windows. Use linux and nano https://imgur.com/a/fSHBLth

Answer (score 0):

After some tests I get solution

Use `--format="[some parameters]"` instead `--format "[some parameters]"`

```
function dinfoip() {
   docker inspect --format="{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" "$1"
}
```