# Escaping double and singing quotes in zsh alias

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to replicate the outcome of the answer to this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7951/escaping-quotes-in-zsh-alias) but with a different command.

I've tried to copy the answer for mine but I keep getting an error in zsh when loading the terminal

```
/Users/k/.zshrc:155: defining function based on alias `convert'
/Users/k/.zshrc:155: parse error near `()'
```

Here the command I'm trying to create an alias for

```
awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' SOME_FILE_NAME.pem
```

And I would like to alias it to

```
convert SOME_FILE_NAME.pem
```

This is what I've tried in zshrc

```
conv() {
    awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' "$@"
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do with an alias. You have a shell function, so it doesn't seem necessary to have an alias. The error says something about an alias called `convert` which you don't show, and you also don't show the function that causes the error.  Where is the quoting issue that you mention in the title?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to define a function whose name is already defined as an alias. Either unset the alias (with `unalias`) or pick a different name for your function.

Comment: If you just want to convert `\r` (carriage return, CR) to `\n` (line feed, LF), you can use much simpler `tr '\r' '\n' < SOME_FILE_NAME.pem`. To remove `\r`, use `sed 's/\r//g' SOME_FILE_NAME.pem` instead.

Answer (score 2):

To create an alias for that, you'd do:

```
alias conv='awk '\''NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}'\'
```

To create a function:

```
conv() awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' "$@"
```

But if you had the `alias` defined already before you ran that `conv` function definition command, the `conv` in there would be expanded to the alias definition, resulting in `zsh` trying to interpret something like:

```
awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}'() awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' "$@"
```

Causing the kind of errors you're seeing.

You have to choose: either use an alias or a function, not both.

To remove an alias (so you can define a function instead):

```
unalias conv
```

Comment: Or, since this is zsh, use the `function conv { … }` syntax to create the function, which works regardless of whether there is already an alias. But of course if you then call `conv` it will call the alias if there is one.

Comment: The trick of using the `function` keyword also works in Bash. (Though Bash produces a more confusing error message when the keyword is missing.)